# c# overwriting/saving current file

Tags: c#, file, save, overwrite

I am doing editor in c#, windows forms. I wish to save 'new content' of file in the same file (usual usage of 'save' option) but I receive IOException,  [ the process cannot access the file ' filename' because it is being used by another process.
 I have method that writes to a NEW file and it works. How to use it to overwrite current file.

Edit:
I am using binarywriter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atxb4f07.aspx

Comment: How are you opening the textfile? It's probably just a case of setting the overwrite flag...

Comment: can you show the code you are using right now to save the file?

Comment: How have you opened the file? Without some code it will be very hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: POssible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are that when you loaded the file, you didn't close the `FileStream` or whatever you used to read it. Always use a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for your streams (and other types implementing `IDisposable`), and it shouldn't be a problem. (Of course if you *actually* have that file open in a separate application, that's a different problem entirely.)

So instead of:

```
// Bad code
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("foo.txt");
string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Nothing is closing the reader here! It'll keep an open
// file handle until it happens to be finalized
```

You should use something more like:

```
string data;
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("foo.txt"))
{
    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
// Use data here - the handle will have been closed for you
```

Or ideally, use the methods in [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) which do it all for you:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("foo.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if you're closing stream to the file. If not then you're blocking yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have correctly closed the stream you used to open and read the file initially, to create, append or fail depending of file existence you should use the FileMode parameter in FileStream constructor.

Everything depends on the way you open the FileStream, see here: [FileStream Constructor (String, FileMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx)

if you specify [FileMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) Create:

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the
>   file already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires
>   FileIOPermissionAccess.Write. System.IO.FileMode.Create is equivalent
>   to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew;
>   otherwise, use Truncate. If the file already exists but is a hidden
>   file, an UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown.